# Fragment button not opening new activity

Tags: android

I've incorporated a horizontal slide navigation component (which required making the class extend Fragment). The slide part works fine. Here i have respective `onClick()` buttons which open a new activity. If I add a button into one of those activities I'm not finding a way to have the displayed activity subsequently refresh. I would think inflating an activity from a button within a fragment would be possible but anything I try stops the emulator.

There's not much to my code so far, so I'm not going to clutter my question with the associated layout part. Any help is certainly appreciated.

Fragment #1’s Java code

public class TasksFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);

    Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_create_appraisal_rpt);
    ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AppraisalReportActivity appraisalRptAct = new AppraisalReportActivity();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, appraisalRptAct);
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(fragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

---

Fragment #1 (portion), which has the button that should initiate aa refresh of this Fragment #1 with Fragment #2

---

Fragment #2 that's to supersede/refresh the previous fragment when Fragment #1's button is clicked

Comment: you should include the code you have anyways. It will give us a better idea of how we can help you :)

Comment: provide your code that you are using

Comment: I tried to include my code in my query, but the section had a limiting word count- not to mention it gave me flak over indenting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean. Do you want to click Button in Fragment to jump to another Activity?

If it is,I think maybe you can try use `getActivity()` to make Activity are working.
for example:

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Activity.class))
```

I hope my answer will help you

Comment: Well, I think I've made progress (and thank you for your response btw). I was trying to have a fragment use a button to replace itself with a new fragment. I think I've gotten my code to be what is structurally/syntactically correct, but when I try it out in an emulator what had been a fragment button that when clicked stopped the emulator it now doesn't do anything- and the Logcat doesn't indicate an error. I'd like to include my code here but this section seems to be limited to a character count. I'll try to include the pertinent parts somehow.